# Exclude SQL statements in Audit logs for Azure SQL Server using Set-AzSqlServerAudit

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm trying to remove all Select statements from Log Analytics of Microsoft Azure SQL server. I found in Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqlserveraudit?view=azps-10.1.0) that introducing PredicateExpression in Set-AzSQLServerAudit can help me to achieve this. I tried couple of expressions to disable the logs using Powershell Cmdlet, however I still see the logs with Select statements with the same pattern as in Predicate expression.

I tried with following predicate expression already, but it still I see Select statements.

`Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ServerName "mysqlserver" -PredicateExpression "statement <> 'exec sp_executesql N%select%' or statement <> 'SELECT 1%'"`

and also, with this one

`Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ServerName "mysqlserver" –PredicateExpression “statement <> ‘exec sp_executesql N’select%’' or statement <> 'SELECT 1%'”`

Anyone has idea where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try the following predicate expression to see if it meets your expectations?

```
Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ServerName "mysqlserver" -PredicateExpression "statement not like '%select%'"
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working using proper escaping and using NOT LIKE
`Set-AzSqlServerAudit -ResourceGroupName "myresourcegroup" -ServerName "mysqlserver" -PredicateExpression "statement NOT LIKE 'exec sp_executesql N''select%' AND statement NOT LIKE 'SELECT 1%'"
`

Comment: I am glad. Thank for sharing with the community the adjustments you made.